# How to conditionally init const char* arr[] with ternary operator

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, conditional-operator

**TLDR;**

How to conditionally init a `const char* []` ?

```
const char* arr[] = (some_condition ? {"ta", "ta"} : {"wo", "lo", "lu"});
```

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token (...) 
> error: expected ‘:’ before ‘{’ token (...) 
> error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token (...) 
> error: invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘const char**’ [-fpermissive]

---

**Details**

I'm using an external api that takes a `const char* argv[]` as input. Based on variables stored in more sane data structures, like `std::string`, I construct this input variable, but I'm obviously unable to do so correctly.

To be honest, the root of the problem boils down to a single trouble argument which is optional. The following works (somewhat) ..

```C++
bool use_optional = false;
std::string optional = "blah";

const char* arr[] = {
    "arg1",
    (use_optional ? optional.c_str() : ""),
    "arg3" 
};
```

The problem with this solution is that I get an empty entry in `arr`, i.e. `{"arg1", "", "arg3"}`, and I would very much like to avoid this.

Comment: Since the size of an array needs to be known at compile time, you cannot do this. You will need to allocate an array dynamically (e.g.: via a `std::vector<const char*>`)

Comment: The result expressions of a conditional expression must both be of the same type.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it is most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can create 2 different arrays, and switch between them:

```
const char* arr1[] = {"ta", "ta"};
const char* arr2[] = {"wo", "lo", "lu"};
auto arr = some_condition ? arr1 : arr2;
```

Another possibility is to use vectors:

```
std::vector<const char*> varr;
varr.push_back("arg1");
if (use_optional) varr.push_back(optional.c_str()),
varr.push_back("arg3");
auto arr = &varr[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, that would have worked! However, number of args is rather long and chunky, so it's a little unpractical. Nevertheless, I really appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: Ref the edit; this works neatly. Thanks! I see now that this is what @UnholySheep referred to in his comment, also.